# Spring-boot plugin for sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

My goal is to package an executable spring-boot jar - a web app with tomcat embedded. I would like to use sbt but I don't find a straight forward way to do this. There are maven and gradle spring-boot plugins, but I don't see anything even close in sbt. My question is - is there a spring-boot sbt plugin, if not, is such functionality planned?